# Uploading and Downloading Files using fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, fog

When uploading and downloading files using fog, I've seen a couple different ways to do it. Which is preferred or does it even matter?

**Uploading**

```
directory.files.create(key: local_filename,
                       body: File.open(local_path),
                       public: false)
```

or

```
connection.put_object(directory.key, 
                      local_filename,
                      File.open(local_path),
                      public: false)
```

and for downloading I only have one example, but needed to change the file options to 'wb' to get it to work:

**Downloading**

```
File.open(Rails.root.join(file.key), 'wb') do |local_file|
  local_file.write(file.body)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great questions.

The `directory.files.create` version ends up calling `connection.put_object` under the covers, so functionally they should be equivalent in basic usage. That being said, `directory.files.create` is the preferred option because it allows you (in many cases) to change which storage provider you are using and have things "just work" (even if the method for uploading on that provider looks quite different).

On the downloading side, there should be a similiar `directory.files.get` vs `connection.get_object` type distinction to get a reference to the object. You'll want the `directory` version, and then calling the `body` method, as you do, should give you the contents to do with as you need to.

Hope that clarifies.